# Solving second order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Having the following second order ordinary differential equation:

$$
\ddot{x} = a \cos(x)
$$

where, $a$ is a constant. What's an approach to solve this kind of equation?

Comment: Oops, my bad. If you really mean $\cos (\color{red}x)$, disregard my comment above. Is this the case?

Comment: yes! it's $\ddot{x} = cos(x)$

Comment: You could solve by first multiplying both sides by $\dot{x}$ and then integrating as follows
$$
\ddot{x}\dot{x} = a\cos\left(x\right)\dot{x}
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}{\frac{\dot{x}^{2}}{2}} = \frac{d}{dx}a\sin(x)
$$
or 
$$
\frac{\dot{x}^{2}}{2}- a\sin(x) = C
$$
this leads to
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin(x) + C}} = \sqrt{2a}t + C_{1}
$$
Which I think is non-trivial to solve. I just absorbed coefficients into constants i.e. C.

Comment: If I may ask, where is this equation coming from ? There is an analytical solution but it is so complex that I shall not report it.

Comment: It's from car kinematics. I'm trying to calculate the slip angular a car reaches while driving through a bend for a given velocity.

Comment: If you shift $x$ by $\pi/2$ you get the equation for the pendulum, which has a known exact solution in terms of Jacobi's sn function.