# Door mechanism differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I have been wondering about a door mechanism I have seen. It has a wire attached to the upper corner of the door and from there to the corresponding corner in the door frame, where a weight hangs from it on a "frictionless" roller. So when the door is opened the weight will rise and then be pulled down by gravity when you let go of the door, closing it.

Considering a door with width $L$ and moment of inertia $J$ what is  the angle of the door $A$ as a function of time with some initial angle $A_0$?

So after doing some math I get to $A''(t)=k\cos(A(t)/2)$ where $k$ is a bunch of constants

How do I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [similar equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772611/solving-second-order-nonlinear-ode#comment1603735_772611).

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of $k$? You may try a perturbation approach in order to approximate the solution.

Comment: On this site itself please try for " non-linear pendulum".